# not able to start application jhipster with mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, jhipster

i am creating an application using jhipter,i set mysql for dev and prod when i change the address in the datasource and the pom.xml for liquibase always i have the error **Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

I executed also **GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'** but always the same error.
for pom.xml :

```
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crud</url>
                <defaultSchemaName>crud</defaultSchemaName>
                <username>root</username>
                <password>0000</password>
                <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.semah.crud.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <logging>debug</logging>
            </configuration>
```

for application-dev.yml :

```
spring:
profiles:
    active: dev
    include: swagger
devtools:
    restart:
        enabled: true
    livereload:
        enabled: false # we use Webpack dev server + BrowserSync for livereload
jackson:
    serialization.indent_output: true
datasource:
    driver: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crud?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
    name: crud
    username: root
    password: 0000
    hikari:
        data-source-properties:
            cachePrepStmts: true
            prepStmtCacheSize: 250
            prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
            useServerPrepStmts: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a password that contains only numbers, you need to add quotes around it is interpreted as a String value.

```
password: "0000"
```